# How to create warning popup while click on save button in interactive grid in oracle apex

Tags: modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I am trying to rectify how I can create a warning/dialog box while clicking to save button used in an interactive grid. That warning/dialog box has two options:

1. Save which will submit modified user data to database
2. Cancel which will not submit modified data.

Currently, we are using Oracle Apex version 5.1.4

Comment: I guess you could do a button that makes a popup modal dialog on which you have text and two buttons, one to actually save and one to cancel.

Comment: I have to create new button on interactive grid for that and made necessary changes which already working very fine. There isnt any way by doing that we can create dialog/warning block which will ask user to processed with changes or not? any javascript or any apex option that can be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, how to stop the standard save action on the IG button, so I propose to hide it and create another one.

1. Hide standard save button. Put `gridID` to the field `Static ID` of your interactive grid, add the following inline CSS style to the page:

   ```
   #gridID button[data-action="save"] {
     display: none !important;
   }
   ```
2. Create a region (which will be your modal dialog) on the page, set properties: `Position` - `Inline Dialogs`, `Template` - `Inline Dialog`, `Static ID` - whatever you want, but unique for the page (I use `mod` further).
3. Create buttons `OK` and `Cancel` in this region.
4. Create a new button with the name `SAVE`.
5. Add a Dynamic Action to the Save button. True Action type - `Execute JavaScript Code`, the code:

   ```
   openModal('mod'); // use here the Static ID of modal dialog
   ```
6. Add a Dynamic Action to the Cancel button. True Action type - `Execute JavaScript Code`, the code:

   ```
   closeModal('mod');
   ```
7. Add a Dynamic Action to the OK button. True Action type - `Submit page`, `Request / Button Name` - `OK`.
8. Open the list of processes, find the standard save process for the IG, set there the value `When Button Pressed` - `OK`.

**UPD** How to replace the Standard Save button with the new one.

9. Set a static ID to the Save button (for example, `savebtn`)
10. Add the following js code to the page properties, `Execute when page loads`:

    ```
    var oldBTN = document.querySelector('#gridID button[data-action="save"]');
    var newBTN = document.querySelector('#savebtn');
    oldBTN.parentNode.insertBefore(newBTN, oldBTN);
    ```

After that everything should work as you want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution,
I tried, working on your given solution. I hide "save" button of IG then created one region on the same page where its type is "Static Content",Static Id as "mod" , position and Template is "inline Dialogs". Two button creates on that region one is "Ok" and second is "Cancel". as mentioned i created dynamic action as well. Created "Save" but on main page which will call to second region. Problem i facing is 1) Save button i created as position "Above Region" which i want replacing actual IG save button. 2) Dynamic action is not working on clicking of "Save" button

Comment: Let me know if i done anything wrong in any step and If you can share some more solution on my problem then its very helpful. I almost close to complete this. Thanks once again.

Comment: I don't remember if you can have a process run right after a dynamic action, but I suppose you could try to have a save process run when your custom save button gets clicked. Theoretically it should run the dynamic actions and then the process to save the data.

Comment: Actually, While clicking Save button it should open model dialog to ask but nothing happens.

Comment: @harshkumarsatapara Check what is written in the console.

Comment: @harshkumarsatapara Check also: button `Save` paroperties, Behavior section, `Action` - `Defined by Dynamic Action`. Check that there is no conditions on Dynamic Action. Also, try to set in DA's properties `Event Scope` - `Dynamic`.

Comment: @harshkumarsatapara I added two steps to the answer how to put the new save button at the same place as an old one.

Comment: Thanks. i got the solution. @Dmitriy -- Thank you so much for your help..